# Python playing around with images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have several images like following:
[image]
I need to have the following output:
[image]
I need to remove shadows and whitespace (or blackspace) from the image background and turn it into a transparent color. What method should I use in python to remove similar colors (like magic wand)?

Here is the code I am using to remove just the whitespace:
from PIL import Image

```
img = Image.open('images/img1.jpg')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save("images/img1_out.png", "PNG")
```